# Google Admob mediation

Tags: ios, admob, ads

I am new for admob, i am integrating admob in my iOS application, everybody suggesting to use mediation, anyone can please expain what is mediation in Admob? how it worsk? and what are the step to integrate & test mediation in  iOS.

Comment: Start here https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/mediation-networks

Comment: do i needs to add every framework for mediation.

Comment: Yes, you need to ad every network that you intend on using.